# Difference between class_name object_name() , class object_name = class_name() and class_name object

Tags: c++, oop, constructor, default-constructor

Please look at those 3 line.

1. A a() - this printed nothing,
2. A a - this printed perfectly,
3. A a = A() - this also printed perfectly in the below code.

```
class A
{
public:

    A()
    {
        cout<<"Empty"<<endl ;
    }



};

int main()
{
    A a() ; // Print Nothing
    A a1;  // Printed
    A a2 = A() ; // Printed


}
```

Why is this happening? I know about default constructor, explicit and implicit call. Moreover in 3rd point what A() returns to left side *A a* ?

`A a = A();`

Comment: tl;dr:  `A a();` declares a function named `a` that takes no arguments and returns an object of type `A`.

Comment: To never have this issue, you can use uniform initialization `A a{};` which usually (but not always) does the right thing.

Comment: @EhasanPial it *declares* a function. Doesn't call a function.

Comment: Thanks sir, I understood :) thank you so much. @AyxanHaqverdili